JavaFX stage size too small - Gridpane resizing
I created a JavaFX dialog in SceneBuilder. After playing probably an hour with the different layout attributes I can't find out how to open the stage in way, that all ui elements are properly displayed.
This is the way the stage opens:

You see, most columns are squeezed.
The gray area below the Monday-Combobox, is actually another ComboBox, which is filled when initializing the UI with a number of ~20 character long Strings. But when opening, there is no default selection. Therefore, this ComboBox is blank.
This is how I would like the stage to open (after enlarging the stage with the mouse) .

I guess the issue is related to a missing resize of the stage after filling the ComboBox, triggering a resize of the ComboBox at the cost of the other columns. But this is just a guess. I wonder which setting is missing or wrong.
I am not after a solution, which is based on brut force setting the width programatically to a certain value or where I have to go through the interface and calculate the width of the stage based on the prefered width of the children. I am hopeing for a set of layout settings that does the trick.
This is the fxml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane fx:id="parentGridPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" stylesheets="@application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="de.levin.ctrl.TrainingPlanEditorCtrl">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="startHourComboBox" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets top="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="startMinutesComboBox" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets right="6.0" top="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="endHourComboBox" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="12.0" top="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="endMinutesComboBox" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="12.0" right="6.0" top="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </ComboBox>
      <Label text=":" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="3.0" right="3.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text=":" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="3.0" right="3.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="Start" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="12.0" right="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="End" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="12.0" right="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="addDayButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addDay" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="5">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets right="12.0" top="12.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="addIntervallButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addIntervall" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="12.0" top="12.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <Separator prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="6.0" top="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Separator>
      <Button fx:id="okButton" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ok" text="OK" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="24.0" top="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="cancelButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" text="Cancel" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="24.0" top="6.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <ScrollPane fx:id="daysScrollPane" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowSpan="3" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <content>
            <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="dayComboBox">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="6.0" right="12.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </ComboBox>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="sessionComboBox" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="12.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </ComboBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </content>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets right="12.0" top="12.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" />
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
   </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>


After you have populated the data in the UI, show the stage for the first time or call sizeToScene on the stage.  Either way it will do the same thing.  Does it do what you want?

You can also preview the UI in SceneBuilder after choosing to show sample data from a menu. The preview will show the UI with lorem ipsum (looked fine to me).

SceneBuilder shows the labels correctly - given that there is no data, which is widening the large ComboBox. sizeToScene results also in the first picture with the too narrow width.

But why is there no data? I suggested calling sizeToScene or initially showing the stage "After you have populated the data in the UI."  In scene builder you can see what the scene looks like with sample data, using the preview feature I also mentioned.

If, instead, you want to display the UI without data but with space reserved for when data will be available, you need to provide sizing hints to set the preferred or minimum size of the UI to reserve that space.  The way to provide sizing hints differs by control or layout. Keep the sizing hints to a minimum, to let the layout respond dynamically where it can.  An example could be setting a minimum size for the surrounding GridPane to 1000x800, and/or setting a preferred row and column count on a TextArea. This can be done in code, FXML, or CSS.  As you are using FXML for layout, use that.

The reason I am commenting and not providing an answer at the moment is that the UI is complex and don't know all your requirements.  If I did answer with an example it would be for a greatly simplified UI to demonstrate concepts, but then I don't know it would actually address and fix your actual issues.  There are layout tutorials that would handle the concept description better anyway, for example: the Oracle tips on sizing and aligning nodes.
